# Running a J2EE/Grails app as a windows desktop application

Tags: deployment, grails, jakarta-ee, installation, jetty

I'd like to do the following but am not sure if it can be done and if so how. Create a Grails application on my local machine and test it. Then somehow package it up along with the Jetty server, and install it on a users desktop. The installer would put an icon in the start menu that would launch the server and load the start page in either the users default browser, or a Java application that would imbed the webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Jetty is not a high priority item you can try the [Winstone servlet container](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/). You can create an "executable war file" which either can be deployed on a servlet container or simply start with java -jar your.war.

Winstone integration for Grails are [on radar](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-99) so maybe Grails can produce "executable war" in the future.

The start menu and desktop integration can be quite easily created using an installer creation software (e.g. [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/)).

**UPDATE:** it seems that there is something work differently (or broken) in winstone from version 0.9.5 (it was the first version which supports Servlet 2.5/JSP 2.1). I tried some older versions and 0.8.1 seems to work fine with my test Grails application.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this out now. I'd rather use Jetty since Winstone hasn't been updated in over a year but if this works I may just stick with it.

Comment: The app runs, but I am unable to  get database controlers to work using an imbedded database, I'll have to see about using one that isn't imbedded.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I have just tried a simple Grails application and I got empty pages as well :( Trying to figure out what the hell is happening...